# Toggle table row siblings

Tags: jquery

I have a table structured like this:

```
<table>
<tr id="id1" class="parent"></tr>
<tr class="id1"></tr>
<tr class="id1"></tr>
<tr class="id1"></tr>
<tr class="id1"></tr>

<tr id="id2" class="parent"></tr>
<tr class="id2"></tr>
<tr class="id2"></tr>
<tr class="id2"></tr>
<tr class="id2"></tr>

.....etc
</table>
```

As you can see child classes are coresponding to their parent id. Now I want to toggle all the rows which have class names equal to their parent row id whenever parent row is clicked.

I have tried this, perhaps stupid try:) and can't seem to get this working:

```
  $('tr.parent').click(function() {
    //alert('yay');
    var tog = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).siblings().hasClass(tog).slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, here ya yo:

```
$('tr.parent').click(function() {
  var tog = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).siblings('.' + tog).slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

`.hasClass()` returns a boolean, it checks if an element has a class, you want to filter by the class. `.siblings()` accepts a selector filter, [see here for details](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

If the child rows are always after like your example, you can make this a bit more efficient as a forward only lookup with [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) like this:

```
$('tr.parent').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.' + $(this).attr('id')).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Works like a charm. Thank you very much as always, Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('table').children('tbody').toggle(false);
        $(".lnkToggle").bind('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').toggle();
        });

    });
</script>
```

HTML Table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left; width: 250px;">
                <i class="lnkToggle" title="Click to view cases"> + </i>
                MOVIES
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>MATRIX</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOY STORY</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>THE GOONIES</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```